# How To get Yaml file configuration in Kubernetes for different workloads without missing something or some parameter in the Exam

Tags: kubernetes, microk8s

i have A CKA exam in a week or so, and i have a great issue with the identation, parameters and other configurations for different workloads in kubernetes.

for example they ask me to create ingress file, i need to remember all the arguments that i should add, and know how i can create an ingress file from something already existed on the cluster.
ps: i know the commnd "-o yaml" but thats not existed for different workloads, it's for only few ones.

i have tried this commands:

$ k get ingress -A

and sure there's nothing and i forget the configuration all the time.

Answer (score 1):

You can always use the cli to create scaffold yamls for you with a combination of "--dry-run=client" and "-o yaml".

e.g. `kubectl create deployment blubb --image bitnami/nginx --dry-run=client -o yaml` results in

```
kind: Deployment
metadata:
 creationTimestamp: null
 labels:
   app: blubb
 name: blubb
spec:
 replicas: 1
 selector:
   matchLabels:
     app: blubb
 strategy: {}
 template:
   metadata:
     creationTimestamp: null
     labels:
       app: blubb
   spec:
     containers:
     - image: bitnami/nginx
       name: nginx
       resources: {}
status: {}
```

you can use `kubectl expose deployment $deploymentname --dry-run=client -o yaml` to generate a service definition.

if you are in need of an ingress, simply use `kubectl expose svc $servicename -n $namespace --dry-run=client -o yaml`

for (cluster-)roles `kubectl create role blubb --resource deployment --verb get,list,watch --dry-run=client -o yaml`

and for (cluster-)rolebindings `kubectl create rolebinding test -n default --clusterrole admin --user foo --dry-run=client -o yaml`

get comfortable with creating scaffolding yamls via the cli, redirect them to a local file using "> $filename" and then change it to what you need.